# class method telling me that I used 1 more pos. argument than needed, but i didnt

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I get the following error from my code: `TypeError: get_manifest() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

I have a `class` `scan`, and `get_manifest` is a function in `scan`:

```
import amfy
import requests
import json
from datetime import timedelta, datetime 
class Scan:
        def __init__(self, realm = 416, cluster = 9):

            self.events = list()
            self.url = "http://realm{}.c{}0.castle.rykaiju.com/api/locales/en/get_serialized_new".format(realm, cluster)


        def get_manifest():                 
            self.request = requests.get(self.url)

            if self.request.status_code == 200:
                self.manifest = self.request.json() if "json" in self.request.headers["content-type"] else amfy.loads(self.request.content)

            else:
                self.manifest = {"failed": req.reason}



        def get_time(day):

            self.today = datetime.now()

            self.plusdays = timedelta(days = day)

            self.new_date = sel.ftoday + self.plusdays

            self.year, self.month, self.day = self.new_date.year, self.new_date.month, self.new_date.day

            if len(str(self.day)) == 1:
                day = "0{}".format(self.day)

            if len(str(self.month)) == 1:
                month = "0{}".format(self.month)

            self.date = str(self.year) + str(self.month) + str(self.day)

            return self.date


        def search_events():

            for day in range(0, 11):
                date = self.get_time(day)

                for section in doaManifest:                
                    for key, value in doaManifest[section].items():                    
                        if date in key:
                            event_title = key 
                            try:
                                event_desc = value['text']
                            except KeyError:
                                event_desc = """" /!\ No Event Description /!\""""
                            my_dict = {'title' : event_title, 'contents' : event_desc}
                            self.events.append(my_dict)
```

Then, in another class, which is my app GUI (written with tkinter), I have a button that calls on this class. The button's command is this:

```
def scan(self):

    if self.scan['text'] == 'Scan':
        self.scan['text'] = 'Re-Scan'
        self.scanned = True

    self.scan = Scan()
    self.scan.get_manifest()
    self.scan.search_events()
```

I don't feed `get_manifest` any arguments, so why is it saying I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you forgot adding `self` to `get_manifest()`. Redefine `get_manifest()` like so:

```
def get_manifest(self):
    code...
```

Instance methods should always accept `self` as the first argument as it's automatically inserted. You may use `@staticmethod` if you don't wish to receive it but as you're using `self` I guess that it's not something you want.

Comment: So I would use `self.scan.self.get_manifest` and `self.scan.self.search_events()`?

Comment: Whoops, you're right! class `scan` was originally just one file that did it's own thing, so I forgot to pass self through

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the `self` parameter to all class methods unless you use `@staticmethod`. So your class should look like this:

```
class Scan:
    def __init__(self, realm = 416, cluster = 9):

        # code...

    def get_manifest(self):                 

        # code...

    def get_time(self, day):

        # code...

    def search_events(self):

        # code...
```

Furthermore, to use this class within your `scan()` method you need to initialize and save the class instance to a variable, then call on the `get_manifest()` method from the saved instance variable.

```
def scan(self):
    # I assume this scan() method is actually a part of a class since 'self' is used

    if self.scan['text'] == 'Scan':
        self.scan['text'] = 'Re-Scan'
        self.scanned = True

    #self.scan = Scan()  # You are overwriting the definition of 'scan' here...

    # So instead do the below

    # Initialize and save your Scan() instance to a variable
    scan_instance = Scan()

    # Now you may use the object's methods 
    scan_instance.get_manifest()
    scan_instance.search_events()

    # Here you can now access the object's attributes that were created in get_manifest()
    print(scan_instance.manifest)
```